# download PGP/mime?

Tags: windows, email

1- it is PGP/mime (GPG) free for windows ... if yes do you have i direct link to download it

2- how i can install it ?

3- if i download it , the command line it is built in or i should download plug-in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPG4Win is available for free on Windows.

http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html

I believe this guide should help you out regarding installation. Also there are instructions for using it through command line.

[How to Use GPG4Win.pdf](http://www.washad.org/docs/How%20to%20Use%20GPG4Win.pdf)

Hope it helps. Good luck!